# search in ICollection entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, collections

I have ICollection Actors in my models. Actors have name param.
I wanna select Movie with Actor with chosen Name. SearchActor string in button,

```
namespace AEXSoft.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string  Date { get; set; }
    public int Budget { get; set; }
    public string  Genre { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

}

In Movie controller I made query

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchActor))
                {  
                     Movie = Movie.Where(c => Actors.Name.Contains(c.Actors.SearchActor));
                }
 return View(Movie.ToList());
```

*

> 'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no
>   extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ICollection' could  Is this correct?

*

And same task but searcging all Actors.

```
Movie=ctx.Movie.Where(s => s.Actors.Contains(SearchActor)).SelectMany(u => u.Actors).ToList();
```

Comment: The firsr query will return List of Movies ie. List<Movie> with selected actor (and not just single one)..do you want that? The second one the same but with movies..if you want just single one, use .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Yes, I want list of movies with selected Actor. This is true, But I think about another question how can Iwrite query to search specific movie with specific actor.

Comment: I would test my code later

Comment: Thanks, Petr Adam!

Comment: To select specific Movie and Actor I would try this
Movie = Movie.Where(c => Actors.Name.Contains(c.Actors.SearchActor)).Where(x => Movie.Title.Contains(x.Title.SearchMovie));

Comment: You can simplify it like this: Movies = Movie.Where(c => c.Actors.Name.Contains(SearchActor) && c.Title.Contains(SearchMovie)).ToList()

Comment: Thanks. I read similar thing in forum. I need learn more. Thank you!

Comment: I have error and my code does not work.

Comment: Can you specify it?

Comment: Yellow text in my first post

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in hint, I was blind..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like that

```
var movieList = Movie.Where(c => c.Actors.Any(i => i.Name.Contains(SearchActor))).ToList()
```

Comment: Yes. It works.  But I chage it to  {Movie = Movie.Where(c => c.Actors.Any(i => i.Name.Contains(SearchActor)));} return View(Movie.ToList());

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to correctly use lamba methods like: ***.Where(c => c.Actors...)***
Second, here ***c.Actors.SearchActor*** you are trying to access property SearchActor on List..there is none obviously.

Try this instead:

```
var SearchActor = "Arnold";

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchActor))
{
    var allMovies = Movie.Where(m => m.Actors.Any(a => a.Name.Contains(SearchActor))).ToList();
}
```